# C# Custom event is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, webforms

I know there is some question about this issue on stackOverFlow right now,But none of them solve my problem.

I use "asp.net webform" and in my `UserControl` I want when I hit a `Button`, fire an event in the page that use this `UserControl`. so this is my code.

```
// in user control
public delegate void OnConversationSubmitDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event OnConversationSubmitDelegate OnConversationSubmitEvenet;

protected void btnUserSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OnConversationSubmitEvenet != null) //This is always null
    {
        OnConversationSubmitEvenet(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

// in main page
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControls.ConversationBox m = new UserControls.ConversationBox();
    m.OnConversationSubmitEvenet += new UserControls.ConversationBox.OnConversationSubmitDelegate(Test_Event);
}

public static void Test_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string g = "sdfsd";
}
```

The problem is `OnConversationSubmitEvenet` is always null an `Test_Event` method never run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be that you are creating a new `ConversationBox`in Page_Load, but I suspect that since you have not added it to the page controls, that you also added a ConversationBox in the aspx?

If you did add a ConversationBox in the aspx, then instead of this:

```
 UserControls.ConversationBox m = new UserControls.ConversationBox();
 m.OnConversationSubmitEvenet += new UserControls.ConversationBox.OnConversationSubmitDelegate(Test_Event);
```

You should use the ConversationBox you added in the aspx:

```
myConversationBox.OnConversationSubmitEvenet += new UserControls.ConversationBox.OnConversationSubmitDelegate(Test_Event);
```

Or alternatively you can remove the one added in the aspx and instead add *m* to the page controls:

```
UserControls.ConversationBox m = new UserControls.ConversationBox();
m.OnConversationSubmitEvenet += new UserControls.ConversationBox.OnConversationSubmitDelegate(Test_Event);
Page.Controls.Add(m); // This line adds the control to the page
```

Comment: yea, definitely the problem is that it is not the same instance you are clicking on your form.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes that was my problem and now its working as i expect.

Answer (score -1):

You should declare 'm' as field in your form, because now 'm' is local variable that disappear after 'Load' method execution.